# Laravel: Class web does not exist

Tags: php, laravel-5

After update composer in laravel 5.2 project not working.

ReflectionException in Container.php line 741: Class web does not exist

please let me know how to solved it.

thanks in advance

Comment: Run `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: `php artisan dump-autoload` You can try this too, It essentially calls `composer dump-autoload` and do some optimizations and generates `bootstrap/compiled.php`

Comment: Is the `'web'` middleware group in your `app/Http/Kernel.php`?